# How to define the rejection region for a permutation test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, permutation-test

I am trying to find out the rejection region for a permutation test about the difference between medians where:

```
 H0: Difference between medians equals 0; 
 Ha: Difference between medians is greater than 0.
```

Considering that I have the distribution of my test statistics on resampled datasets, how can I find the critical value for the test so that I can infer the rejection region?

```
> sum(permstats>=obs.median)/length(permstats) #pvalue
```

It is not completely clear to me how can I find the rejection region according to the permutations distribution( and maybe the p-value??)

Comment: Just to be sure: you are not just interested in finding the corresponding $p$-value associated to your resampling procedure (in which case the Wikipedia entry on [Resampling](http://bit.ly/waHBnQ) might do the job), but rather in expressing a rejection region in a formal way?

Comment: @chl- Yes exactly -just expressing the rejection region

Comment: Well, it’s the $1-\alpha$ quantile of the `permstat` vector...

Comment: @Elvis - that was what I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rejection region you could do something like

```
lbrr <- quantile(permstats, probs=0.95)
print(lbrr)    # lower boundary of one-sided test
if (obs.median > lbrr) {"Reject H0"} else {"Do not reject H0"}
```